# Cannot use pip cmd instead of python -m pip

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, debian

I've been trying to upgrade my python3 installation from 3.9 to 3.11 on my raspberry pi.

After a lot of struggle, I finally reached the point where i can do the following

```
> python -V
Python 3.11.3
> sudo python -V
Python 3.11.3
> pip -V
pip 23.1.1 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
> sudo pip -V
pip 23.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

and yet, if I do `sudo pip list`, I get the following:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 581, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 909, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 800, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 23.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.3.4'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 169, in run
    packages: "_ProcessedDists" = [
                                  ^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 169, in <listcomp>
    packages: "_ProcessedDists" = [
                                  ^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 664, in <genexpr>
    return (d for d in it if d.canonical_name not in skip)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3259, in <module>
    @_call_aside
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 795, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.3.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 581, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 909, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 800, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 23.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.3.4'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 225, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in handle_pip_version_check
    session = self._build_session(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 342, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3259, in <module>
    @_call_aside
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 795, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.3.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

and the same happens for just `pip list`: only the location of the files are different.

BUT...
if I do either `python -m pip list` or `sudo python -m pip list`, now it's a different story:

```
> python -m pip list

Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.1.1
setuptools 67.7.2
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

**EDIT (progress update)**
I realize that I had installed pip using `sudo apt install python3-pip`
which, on rapsberry pi, does not make the latest pip version available...

So I went to `/usr/bin` and renamed both `pip` and `pip3` temporarily

Now, my current workaround is to replace them with a "fake" sh trick:

content of file **/usr/bin/pip3** :

```
python -m pip $@
```

then (with user root in /usr/bin)

```
> chmod +x pip3
> ln -s pip3 pip
```

and this does the trick.

But I'm obviously not very satisfied by this answer.
My current guess is that I'll have to find the right repo and update apt to be able to look inside a better repo.